# Min/Max Formula using data validation

Tags: excel, validation, minmax

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F14),"", IF(ISBLANK(H14),"", IF(AND(F14>=MIN(100), H14=F95:G95, 
F14<=MAX(500), H14=F95:G95),"PASS","FAIL")))
```

The solution displays as #VALUE. I am making a test report that requires user input (F14) and a drop-down list (H14). The user inputs the value, selects one of two options from the drop-down list, and the formula should compute based on those two variables.

For example

```
F14 = 200, H14
```

must be either kHz or MHz. Since 200kHz or MHz would satisfy the formula, the result would be "PASS". If F14 = 50; 50 kHz would FAIL, but 50 MHz would pass.

I made sure that formula is trying to confirm that H14 is set to one of the options in the list

```
(F95/G95)(kHz/MHz).
```

I would accept VBA solutions as well, because I know that even Excel has its limits. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with `H14=F95:G95`? What about `MAX(500)`, which will *always* return 500? And `MIN(100)`, which will *always* return 100?

Comment: Okay so I don't know how I missed the formula, but it pasted weird.....It should look like this: =IF(ISBLANK(F14),"", IF(ISBLANK(H14),"", IF(AND(F14>=MIN(100), F14<=MAX(500), H14=F95:G95),"PASS","FAIL")))

Comment: I don't know what @BigBen means, because if you look at the formula, it says F14 >= Min(100), which returns a true/false when the entry meets the condition. Same goes for F14<=MAX(500). It doesn't return 100 or 500, only if the entry meets those specifications.

Comment: My question is how do you call out the min/max formula and drop-down list so that it satisfies the specifications?

Comment: `F14 >= Min(100)` is equivalent to `F14 >= 100`, the `Min` is redundant. Which is why I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Sorry about that. I removed MIN/MAX from my formula. I'm trying to word it where F14 is a user input and H14 is a dropdown list containing kHz or MHz, the formula will return a pass/fail. The dropdown list points to cells F95 (kHz) and G95 (MHz) So F14 must be greater or equal to 100 (+) kHz in the dropdown list  AND less than/equal to 500 (+) MHz in the dropdown list. Thanks for your patience @BigBen.

Comment: Any chance you could add a screenshot of your setup? I think I understand but it would help.

Comment: I added the screenshot. I've been able to get a similar formula to work, with just a greater than or less than x, but trying to create a formula between kHz and MHz or GHz I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Something like `=IF(OR(AND(H14="kHz",G14>=100,G14<=999),AND(H14="MHz",G14>=0,G14<=500)),"Pass","Fail")`. I'm guessing that 999 kHz is the max amount in kHz that can be entered.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works exactly like it should. Thanks so much for your patience!